# Blog on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Can we create a Share point BLOG site where in I want the users to express their views and Its not available to others ?

We would like the senior management to understand the concerns if their staff.

Comment: In Short: Yes. Now what is the actual code related problem?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is a very powerful tool that comes with a number of built-in workspaces such as Wikis and Blogs, and you can easily activate them.
 Below you will find instructions on how to create a blog on your SharePoint site.

1. Log into SharePoint as a user with Administrator privileges
2. Click Site Actions and then click Create
3. Under Web Pages click Sites and Workspaces
4. Enter the Title, Description, and URL for your Wiki or Blog
5. Choose a Blog template
6. Fill out the rest of your preferences for the navigation and functionality.
7. Finish entering your preferences and click Create.

Look at the following link for comment policy:
[Blog commenting policy](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/2007/07/blog-commenting-policy/)